# Can I run two different mysql docker containers using a shared data volume?

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, volume

Given hypothetical scenario:

1. I have two different identical docker containers (say [nginx proxy manager](https://nginxproxymanager.com/) for example).
2. Both docker containers run on separate host machines with a mounted NFS drive at path /mnt/data.
3. Both docker containers define their mysql data directory as /mnt/data, which is mapped to the same point on the NFS mount.

What potential problems could there be if both applications are running at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,MySQL and MariaDB (that [nginx_proxy_manager documents](https://nginxproxymanager.com/advanced-config/#docker-secrets), are not shared storage databases, and only might detect each others appearance.

You probably can use a database instance shared between two nginx_proxy_manager instances. I don't know if both can share a database or two databases need to be created in the container.